# Generalizing a Fundamental Matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, constants

In [this video](https://youtu.be/zreI4HllD80?t=422) (final result at 8:54), the professor explains that the most general fundamental matrix of a system of linear ordinary differential equations is given by $XC$, where $X$ is any fundamental matrix of the system (the matrix whose columns are a linear independent set of solutions), and $C$ is a matrix of constants.  He makes it sound as if the entries of $C$ for the $2 \times 2$ system are four arbitrary constants which bare no specific relation to each other, except that the determinant of $C$ must not be $0$.

Is this understanding correct?  If so, why is it the case that generalizing the fundamental matrix of a $2 \times 2$ system requires four arbitrary constants, when the system itself only has room for two arbitrary constants?

Comment: Most people (myself included) won't have time to watch a video to answer your question.

Comment: @copper.hat That's why I included a summary of what the professor explains.  Is the question unclear without watching the video?

Comment: Yes, the question is not entirely clear without additional context. It would be helpful if you could indicate at what time in the lecture the professor talks about this. Then people could more easily search for the context needed without watching the entire lecture.

Comment: @user10478: Yes, that is why I added my initial comment. Unfortunately, there are many fundamental things in mathematics and I don't have the energy to watch YouTube just to see if I can help. Also, I am often in contexts where I cannot listen.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the link and added the time of the final result to the question.

Comment: 1. What is the "system" here?  2. I have no idea what a "fundamental matrix" is.  Can you provide a definition?  3. Why is the system two-dimensional (i.e., why is $C$ a 2-by-2 matrix)?  ...

Comment: @sasquires I edited the question to answer 1 and 2.  The system is two-dimensional just to pick the simplest case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I watched about a minute of the video, and I think that the brief answer to your question is that while only two constants are needed to generate all solutions, there is nothing preventing you from having four constants and repeating some of the solutions.

Let me give a simple example.  Suppose you have a fundamental matrix
$$ X = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \end{pmatrix} $$

I can write another fundamental matrix by exchanging the two columns:
$$ Y = \begin{pmatrix} x_{12} & x_{11} \\ x_{22} & x_{21} \end{pmatrix} $$

This is not a new *set of solutions*, because it's the exact same set that you had before. 
 But it is a new *fundamental matrix* because it is represented slightly differently.  The basic problem is that there is some sense in which unique solutions are a "subset" of fundamental matrices (but I am not going to bother to define this rigorously).

In our particular case, you can write
$$ Y = X \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
which agrees with the lecturer's assertion that all fundamental matrices can be written in the form $XC$ for some constant matrix $C$.

The only remaining question is why $C$ must have a nonzero determinant.  Clearly, for $XC$ to be a fundamental matrix, its columns have to be linearly independent and therefore it has to have a nonzero determinant.  But $\det(XC)=\det(X)\det(C)$, so $C$ must also have a nonzero determinant.  (Basically, if $C$ had a zero determinant, then you would end up with a fundamental matrix that has either zero or one independent solutions in it.)